# AG-Grid Vue editor integration: difference between 20.1.0 and 20.2.0

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid, vuetify.js

I'm facing some problems with AG-Grid 20.2.0 enterprise and a custom editor, using Vue 2.6.0 and Vuetify 1.5.9.

The very simple editor component is this one:

```
<template>
    <v-combobox v-model="value" :items="items" hide-details single-line flat solo></v-combobox>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'kus-test',
    data() {
        return {
            items: [],
            value: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getValue() {
            return this.value
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

With AG-Grid 20.1.0, when I write "something" and press enter, the string is saved, the editor closes and I see "something" in the cell.

With AG-Grid 20.2.0, when I press enter, the editor closes and nothing is saved, I see an empty cell andno error arises in the console.

With a slightly more complex editor component, I saw that all `$refs` were set to `undefined`.

I don't know if it's a bug, but it's definitely something with AG-Grid, since my other dependencies stay the same and work well with 20.1.0.

Do you have an idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 22.1.0, and with vuetify 2, this is no longer a problem.